# "SignatureDoesNotMatch" when using axios to put image in Digital Ocean spaces using signed link

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, axios, pre-signed-url

I am trying to insert an image into digital ocean spaces using axios in react native by creating a signed url in node.js. The url gets generated properly, however when I try to insert the image using the url I get "Signature Does Not Match" error. Here is my axios code:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", {
    uri: this.state.image.path,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: data.key
});

axios(data.url, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    method: 'PUT',
    data: fd
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and here is my node.js code:

```
const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint("xyz");

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: "xyz",
    secretAccessKey: "yzx"
});

app.post("/getPreSignedURL", function(req, res) {
        const params = {
        Bucket: "trialspace",
        Key: Math.random() + ".jpg",
        ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", params, function(err, url) {
        console.log("Your generated pre-signed URL is", url);
        var contentType = params.ContentType;
        var key = params.Key;
        res.send({ url, contentType, key });
    });
});
```

However when I use xmlHttpRequest as shown [here](http://blog.rudikovac.com/react-native-upload-any-file-to-s3-with-a-presigned-url/) instead of axios everything works fine. So I don't think there is anything wrong with spaces permission or node server.

Edit:
This is request and response log from axios. For some reason axios is removing my Content Type from header.

[image: Log]

Comment: Remove `'Accept': 'application/json',` and try again.

Comment: no still getting the same error

Comment: `ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'` can't possibly be right, either,  but since you are also using it in the upload headers, it should not be the problem -- it is wrong, but it is consistent in both places, so it should still be accepted.  I suspect that axios may be re-encoding an already-urlencoded signed URL.  That would definitely break the signature.  Capturing what's actually sent on the wire, if possible, might help.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated the answer. I also tried removing the Content Type altogether in order to avoid mismatch but it threw the same error again

Comment: Your signed URLs appear to have `Content-Type=multipart%2Fform-data` in the query string.  There is no `Content-Type` query string parameter documented in the S3 API Reference.  It's not really clear just what is going wrong here.  Please try specifying a content type with no semantic implications, like `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting Authorization headers in transform request as follows:

```
       axios({
            url: "mySignedUrl",
            data: {
                uri: this.state.image.path,
                type: "image/jpeg",
                name: "0.3789520076534978.jpg"
            },
            method: "put",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                "x-amz-acl": "public-read"
            },
            transformRequest: [
                (data, headers) => {
                    delete headers.common.Authorization;
                    return data;
                }
            ]
        })
```

This issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382)